# Redirect www to non www all pages

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, redirect

Yes I know same question has been asked many times already in stackoverflow and my website homepage is being redirected from www to non www successfully

but all the internal pages not being redirected from www to non www. All the code on the internet is working fine to redirect the home from www to non www but internal pages are not redirecting.

1. I have used aws elastic load balaner on website
2. I have redirected http to http using Virtual host file from - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/
3. right now I'm using fillowing code to redirect www to non www

> RewriteEngine On
>       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
>
>       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysiteurl.in/$1 [L,R=301]

What are the changes do I need to do in this code so all the internal pages also redirect from www to non www or it is not possible to do it with aws elb.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working.

Actually, I have a big htaccess file and I was adding code to redirect from www to non www at the end of the file but when I put it at beginning of the file all pages redirecting from www to non www successfully.

it's working that's good but did not get why it was not working for inner pages when the code was added at the end of the file.